# Clustering of Images and Dimensional Reduction using PCA in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

i am doing K means Clustering on image dataset. Firstly, I loaded the images and stored in numpy array. There are 24 images total. the shape of the img_array that I created is (24, 300, 400, 3). To run the K means, I converted it to array of 2 dimension and shape is now, (24,360000). I got a adjusted_rand_score after clustering of 0.57.

I don't know, how to use PCA and and reduce the dimensions of the images and then compare the clustering accuracy.

Now, I need to this use the PCA  to reduce the dimensionality to 400 dimensions, 200 dimensions, 50 dimensions, 5 dimensions, and finally 2 dimensions.

```
    path = "C://Users/shivam/Desktop/data//"
    os.chdir(path)
    for f in os.listdir('.'):
        if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        img = Image.open(f)
        data = np.asarray( img, dtype='uint8' )
        img_array.append(data)
   df = pd.DataFrame({'image_arrays':img_array})
   df['id'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)

   label_list = ['nature','nature','nature','nature','nature','nature','sunset','sunset','sunset','sunset','sunset','sunset','sunset','sunset','sunset','water','water','water','water','water','water','water','water','water']

   df.head()

   img_arr_2D = img_arr.reshape(24,120000) 

   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from matplotlib import style
   style.use("ggplot")
   from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

   X = img_array_2D
   kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, max_iter= 100)
   kmeans.fit(X)

   centroid = kmeans.cluster_centers_
   labels = kmeans.labels_

   colors = ["g.","r.","c."]

   for i in range(len(X)):
       print ("coordinate:" , X[i], "label:", labels[i])
       plt.plot(X[i][0],X[i][1],colors[labels[i]],markersize=10)
       plt.show()

   classes = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
   labels = kmeans.labels_

   from sklearn.metrics.cluster import adjusted_rand_score
   adjusted_rand_score(classes, labels)
```

Comment: Is anybody there, who can help?

Comment: Sure, but your question shows a lack of effort. There are **tons of examples within the docs which use PCA on images**. Also pursuing help with some extra comment 105 minutes after your question is not what i would call good style. There is probably a reason there is no answer. And it's not, that it's too hard!

Comment: hello, but i tried to put everything in the question, I am searching the docs. but unable to get anything. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Even with PCA the results will not improve much (and beware that PCA scales badly with the number of variables, and you would need millions of images to gets reliable result here).

The pixel representation of an image is not good as input. You want something where e.g. the same picture upside down has the same representation.

So you need to do **feature extraction**.

You could do color historgrams, bags of visual words, but for state of the art you'll need to go into deep learning.